# How to store User Roles into the session

Tags: symfony, symfony-security, symfony-2.7

I saw that on every page the user-object gets fetched again from the database. Even though the user-object is serialized correctly, so i thought it is probably because of the relationship to the roles.
How is it possible to store that information into the Session? I added the roles property to the serialize function of the user and added the serializable interface to the roles.

Comment: What is your problem? Roles should be loaded with the user so they should be available if needed.

Comment: My question is: Why do i serialize the User-Object if it gets fetched anyway every sitecall? I store the User-Object and the Roles in my database and i'd like to cache it in the session.

Comment: In production environment ('prod')?

Comment: I only checked in dev environment. Why would it behave different?